# Prime ideals in a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

My question is about prime ideals. If we want to show that ideal $I$ is prime we must take $ab \in I$ and show that $a$ is in $I$ or $b$ is in $I$. Does that mean that in product $ab$ we must take different elements? Always?

Answer (score 3):

No: you never require that $a\neq b$. For example you can show that $(x^2) \subset \Bbb{Q}[x]$ is not a prime ideal because $x \cdot x \in (x^2)$ and $x, x \notin (x^2)$.

P.S. I wrote $x,x \notin (x^2)$ to stress the role of $a=x, b=x$.

Comment: But if we have I = {matrices A={x,x}{x,x}: x integer} and ring S where S/I is isomorphic to ring of integers Z. Then we know that I is prime but we can take zero matrix which is in I and show that matrix {0,1}{0,0} times itself gives us zero matrix but it is not from I.

Comment: I don't understand your example. What is $S$? If you mean $S=M_{2 \times 2} (\Bbb{Z})$, then $I$ is not an ideal.

Comment: No, S={A={x,y}{y,x}: x,y integers} and we have ring homomorphism f:S->Z that {x,y}{y,x} sends to x-y. So, I from my question is kernel of that homomorphism, image of f is Z so we have S/I is isomorphic to Z.

Comment: The matrix {0,1}{0,0} is not in your ring $S$, so your example still does not work.

Comment: Yes, but that is a question, we have {0,0}{0,0} =  {0,1}{0,0} times  {0,1}{0,0} is in I and {0,1}{0,0} is not which means that I is not prime, but we know that is is prime so I don't see what is wrong here.

Comment: You are working in some ring $S$. You wonder if $I$ is a prime ideal of $S$ or not. So why do you take something not in $S$? The definition of prime ideal (I stress "of $S$") involves only elements of $S$.

Comment: Ideal is prime if ab \in I implies a \in I or b \in I. So if I take zero matrix that is in I, I can get in using matrix {0,1}{0,0} so, I have zero matrix \in I implies  {0,1}{0,0} \not in I.

Comment: At this point I must ask you to see again the definition of prime ideal. You are not allowed to use strange objects outside your starting ring.